# how to pass values to the combobox in extjs

Tags: extjs

How can I pass my store data to store in ComboBoX

```
hours_ds: [

    [0, '12AM'], [1, '1AM'], [2, '2AM'], [3, '3AM'],
    [4, '4AM'], [5, '5AM'], [6, '6AM'], [7, '7AM'],
    [8, '8AM'], [9,'9AM'], [10,'10AM'], [11,'11AM'],
    [12, '12PM'], [13, '1PM'], [14, '2PM'], [15, '3PM'],
    [16, '4PM'], [17, '5PM'], [18, '6PM'], [19, '7PM'],
    [20, '8PM'], [21,'9PM'], [22,'10PM'], [23,'11PM']
],
  {
     xtype: 'combo',
     name: 'startHourCombo',
     id: 'startHourCombo_cb',
     queryMode: 'local',
     maxWidth: 80,
     columnWidth: 0.2,
     store: //how to pass my hours_ds values to this combo
     selectOnFocus: true,
     forceSelection: true,
     triggerAction: "all",
     typeAhead: false,
     valueField:'id',
     displayField: 'name'
```

}

Comment: Did you check the doc by any chance http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a store first and then pass that store to the store of your combo.

Here I is the working code.

Here creating a store and setting to variable states. Then calling that states to the store of combobox.

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Check the fiddle . [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26vh)

Answer (score 0):

Though array reference can be passed to a store in a Combobox, as shown in this Fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26vi, but good practice would be to declare a store in a View Model and then bind it to the store config in a Combobox. This will make the code declarative and also allow to reuse the store, if needed.

Data can be hard-coded in a store via **data** config. Refer http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html